# Transferring data between servers

Tags: scripting

I have `SSH` access between two servers `A` (httpmydocs) and `B` and I am transferring data routinely from `A` to `B` using the command line:

```
scp -rpC /var/www/httpmydocs/* mega_me@mega_debian.com:/var/www/httpmydocs
```

Now I want to backup the data from my desktop PC to the server `A` weekly. How can you help me to revise this command line to make it a script running automatically in a specific time and date to back up the data from my Desktop PC to server `A`

Comment: You probably want to use `rsync` with `-e ssh`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely need a specific time and date you should use a cron job. As you normally run this from the commandline, that can be a normal cron job and doens't have to be a system one. `crontab -e` will get you a file to edit to which you add somewhere at the bottom

```
10 2 * * 1 test -x /path/to/yourscript || /path/to/yourscript
```

The first field is minutes, second is hours, fifth is day-of-week.

The file `/path/to/yourscript` should be executable (`chmod +x`) and look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
scp -rpC /var/www/httpmydocs/* mega_me@mega_debian.com:/var/www/httpmydocs
```

That will do what you asked, but that has several problems:

1. It doesn't get started if you machine is down at 2:10 AM on Monday.
2. `scp` does a full copy every time.

For point 2. slm already gave appropriate solutions.

Point 1. can be solved by not using crontab and putting `yourscript` in `/etc/cron.weekly` (as slm also indicated) but you loose control somewhat over when exactly it is run, as the weekly runs are all done after each other at a time specified in `/etc/crontab` (or in `/etc/anacrontab`). You can change the time and day-of-week there, but it affects the other scripts being run as well.

If using `/etc/cron.weekly` unacceptable, you can adapt the approach from [my answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164425/33055) to run at least once a week and after a specific time.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use `scp` I'd use `rsync` for this task or even potentially `rdiff-backup`.

```
$ rsync -avz /var/www/httpmydocs/ \
    mega_me@mega_debian.com:/var/www/httpmydocs/.
```

This will perform a similar backup as the `scp` command, however it'll only transfer the delta of files as they change overtime, or new files, skipping files that have already been copied.

Depending on your intent you can use the `--delete` switch to remove files that are no longer present on the local side from the remote backup.

To make this a scheduled task I'd roll it into a cronjob. Given it's a system-y type of directory, I'd add a crontab entry under `/etc/cron.daily` or `/etc/cron.weekly`, depending on your frequency. Putting the above `rsync` command in a shell script, making it executable, and inside either of those directories, is all that's required to make it occur at one of those 2 frequencies.

#### References

- [rdiff-backup project page](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/)